# view timestamp diff output in 24 hours

Tags: mysql, datetime

I want to be able to view the output of this query in 24 hours form. What I mean is for the output to be like for example

```
5 Day(s) | 21 Hour(s) | 22 Minute(s) | 50 Second(s)
```

currently the output i'm getting is

```
5 Day(s) | 141 Hour(s) | 8488 Minute(s) | 509336 Second(s)
```

This is the date time calculation that I used

```
SELECT

CONCAT( (TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, '2015-04-18 12:49:17', now())), ' Day(s)'),

CONCAT( (TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, '2015-04-18 12:49:17', now())), ' Hour(s)'),

CONCAT( (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '2015-04-18 12:49:17', now())), ' Minute(s)'),

CONCAT( (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '2015-04-18 12:49:17', now())), ' Second(s)')
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`TIME_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format) function, in coordination with the [`TIMESTAMPDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) and [`TIMEDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) function calls:

```
SELECT
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(
        DAY,
        '2015-04-18 12:49:17',
        NOW()
    ) AS 'days',
    TIME_FORMAT(
        TIMEDIFF(
            NOW(),
            '2015-04-18 12:49:17'
        ),
        '%h'
    ) AS 'hours',
    TIME_FORMAT(
        TIMEDIFF(
            NOW(),
            '2015-04-18 12:49:17'
        ),
        '%i'
    ) AS 'minutes',
    TIME_FORMAT(
        TIMEDIFF(
            NOW(),
            '2015-04-18 12:49:17'
        ),
        '%s'
    ) AS 'seconds'
```

Please note that the order of parameter is different for both of them.